# how to add code to Proteus design

Tags: assembly, simulator, x86-16

I have an 8086 assembly code for which I want to design a circuitry in Proteus IsIs. My problem is that I don't know what source code files I can add to Proteus and I didn't find anything of help when I searched. I know there is an "add/remove source files" part in there, but what source files and in which language I am expected to add, I do not know.
Can anybody please help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Which compiler are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am supposing that you are using keil , so you need to create a HEX file to dump in the 8051 microcontroller .

1. Creating a HEX file : if you have made a project see in that folder if there is a HEX file (after compling ur code)  or not , if there is no HEX file , then go to flash -> configure flash tools -> output -> check the create HEX file , and recompile it you will get the hex file in the same folder
2. Now open proteus and make the design which will include the required microcontroller and the double click on the microcontoller and then include that hex file which was created . This way you can simulate your design .

Comment: Sorry it may sound kind of noobish but I code assembly in emulator 8086. The output by default is .asm.
How can I provide the HEX file?

Comment: Ok I found that I can output a binary file with the Emulator if I put the directive #make_bin# in the code. So is this of any help? Can I add the .bin file to the design in the Proteus?

Comment: although i have not personally tried but i checked their website just now and there it is written that we can run .bin file

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me how I can add binary files to a design in Proteus? And by the way, a binary file is chip-dependent. How is Proteus supposed to know what it is running the code on (for example an Intel 8086 compatible chip or a MARS one? )

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a exe file using an assembler and put that file inthe proteus project folder. Once you have that click on the 8086 in proteus and you will see a box where you can specify the the exe file. See this [tutorial on 8086 with proteus ISIS](http://appliedelectronicsengineering.blogspot.in/2015/02/8086-microprocessor-simulation-with.html)